# Создание документа docx на чистом xml без библиотек

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

Есть ли возможность создать ms word (docx) файл на php без использования сторонних библиотек на xml? У меня очень специфическая выгрузка и функционала phpWord не хватает. Могу ли я создать документ сам разметкой xml, по аналогии с тем как мы делаем веб страницы на html, где-то можно посмотреть примеры?
Насколько я знаю docx это просто xml в определенном формате, как это реализовать с php?

Comment: ))))) docx = zip

Comment: Вариантов несколько - можно использовать не `xml`, а `html`-форматирование структуры внутри `docx` - если использовать не все возможности - подойдет, если прямо `xml` - вот тут человек пытался что-то сделать, почитайте - https://habr.com/ru/post/140012/, либо почитать стандарт `odt` - будет конечно не `docx`, но ms office его поймет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Могу ли я создать документ сам разметкой xml, по аналогии с тем как мы делаем веб страницы на html

Да

> где-то можно посмотреть примеры?

Возьмите любой docx файл и переименуйте его в zip
После этого разархивируйте его, - получите xml файлы -
Они и будут Вам примерами.

Удачи!